# Estou usando um Banco mySQL onde armazeno marcadores de um mapa

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, google-maps

Estou usando um Banco mySQL onde armazeno marcadores de um mapa (na tabela armazeno a latitude e a longitude desses marcadores) minha questão é, quero fazer um select pegando todos os marcadores que estão em um raio de proximidade de um ponto (ou marcador), achei essa solução: pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/55669/… no entanto confesso não ter compreendido a solução sugerida, por isso gostaria de auxilio nessa questão.

Comment: Matheus, me de uma luz aqui!!!

Answer (score 2):

A solução seria partindo do seu ponto central traçar um alcance dele, que seria o raio do seu circulo. A fórmula de Haversine retorna na coluna a distância do ponto pesquisado do seu ponto inicial. 
No SELECT a fórmula ficaria em uma coluna e o raio de pesquisa ficaria no seu WHERE.

SELECT (calculo) AS distancia
FROM tabela
WHERE distancia <= 5

Lembrando a distância do WHERE é em quilomêtros, caso queira pesquisar em metros seria 100m = 0.1

Comment: Matheus Zenker,você teria um link ou conseguiria me explicar essa formula, por que não achei nda que me desse um explicação mais clara sobre.

Comment: De uma olhada nesse link http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4906/why-is-law-of-cosines-more-preferable-than-haversine-when-calculating-distance-b

Comment: Matheus,por que quando dou um SELECT id_marker, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians(-18.58589) ) * cos( radians( -46.514950 ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * sin(radians(-18.58589)) ) ) AS distance FROM tb_marker HAVING distance <= 5 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 10
Ele não me retorna coisa alguma!!

Comment: Criei uma tabela para atender seu caso. E funcionou perfeitamente o erro na sua consulta acima está no ponto central e não nos pontos que estão cadastrados. Sua consulta ficaria +- assim: SELECT *, (6371 *
        acos(
            cos(radians(-18.585890)) *
            cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(-46.514950) - radians(lng)) +
            sin(radians(-18.585790)) *
            sin(radians(lat))
        )) AS distance
FROM tabela HAVING distance <= 10

Comment: Note que os outros valores da fórmula são baseados no seu ponto central e nos pontos que serão pesquisados. SELECT *, (6371 *
        acos(
            cos(radians(LAT_PESQUISA_PONTO_CENTRAL)) *
            cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(LNG_PESQUISA_PONTO_CENTRAL) - radians(lng)) +
            sin(radians(LAT_PESQUISA_PONTO_CENTRAL)) *
            sin(radians(lat))
        )) AS distance
FROM tabela HAVING distance <= 5